# Python: append magic

Tags: python, list, append

```
list.append(x)
```

*Add an item to the **end** of the list.*

Okay. Let's write some code:

```
x = [[]]*3
x[0].append('foo')
print x
```

and output is:

```
[['foo'], ['foo'], ['foo']]
```

Why?

Comment: Better question, where does the "real john doe"  come from?  I've heard it before off an album and had no idea what it meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x = [[]]*3` Creates a list of length 3 where each element have the same reference. So appending  to any element will give this result.